# error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `bytesize' Fluentd

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I have the below Fluentd plugin code:

```
require 'avro'

module Fluent
  module TextFormatter

    class Sample
    end

    class AvroFormatter < Formatter
      Fluent::Plugin.register_formatter('avro', self)

      config_param :schema_file, :string, :default => nil
      config_param :schema_json, :string, :default => nil

      def configure(conf)
        super
        if not (@schema_json.nil? ^ @schema_file.nil?) then
          raise Fluent::ConfigError, 'schema_json or schema_file (but not both) is required'
        end
        if @schema_json.nil? then
          @schema_json = File.read(@schema_file)
        end
        @schema = Avro::Schema.parse(@schema_json)
      end

      def format(tag, time, record)
        handler = Sample.new()
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I need to instance the *class* "Sample" in the *def* "Format". The problem is that when I try to do a http POST against Fluentd the below error appears:

```
failed: error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `bytesize'
```

This error only appears when the *class* "Sample" is instanced. I'm new with ruby, and I don't know where is the problem. Should I create the *class* "Sample" in another file?

Comment: Could you show full stack trace of your error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting this error because code, that calls `format` expects string result, but instead it gets an instance of `Sample` class. Try to return some string instead.

You can also use this example here: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/plugin-development#text-formatter-plugins.